# Jquery reset horizontal scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below **script** which automatically **scrolls right** to slide the **images.** Unfortunately I'm not able to **reset** the **counter**.
I've done a condition to see if the **scroll** is **finished**, and if it is then reset the width of the **scroll**, but it seems to not be working. However, if instead of **reseting the scroll**, I place an alert - then resetting the width works, but **scrolling is still not working.**

All is working good until the for **loop ends** and I'm not able to reset the **scroll to the beginning.**

Here is the script:

```
      <script>
 $(function ($) {
  $('#headw').on('scroll', function () {
      if($(this).scrollLeft() + $(this).innerWidth() >= $(this)[0].scrollWidth) {

         // RESET THE COUNTER 
          $("#headw").animate({
                          scrollLeft: "+="+width+"px",
                            }, 3000);

       } 
       else if($(this).scrollLeft() === 0) {

      // Remove this part if you don't want your messages hidden again
      }
      else {

      }
    })
  });



      function doItAll() {
    // put state variables other than the actual loop control here

            function doTheLoop() {
                var i;
                var count;
                var total = <?php echo $row; ?>;
                var tx = total + 1;
                for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {                   

                      var width = $(".divisorx").outerWidth();
                      count = count + width;
                      $("#headw").animate({
                          scrollLeft: "+="+width+"px",
                       }, 3000);

                 }
                return(false);   // done running the loop
              }
            while (doTheLoop()) {}
            // do some things after the loop
           }

          doItAll();


    </script>
```